# nodemcu - problem writing to arbitrary location in memory

Tags: nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

From esp8266 documentation:

> You need to call EEPROM.begin(size) before you start reading or writing, size being the number of bytes you want to use. Size can be anywhere between 4 and 4096 bytes.

I had problem reading/writing to memory when start address was not 0 but some xx address and had to write small test program to check it out.

First code ...

```
EEPROM.begin(16);
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    EEPROM.write(i, i);
}
EEPROM.commit();
EEPROM.end();
```

this is OK. Everything is written correctly.

But if I change start address …

```
EEPROM.begin(20);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    EEPROM.write(i+16, i);
}
EEPROM.commit();
EEPROM.end();
```

it only writes first 4 bytes since in begin I requested 20 bytes.

My question is: Is this normal or is it a bug? In documentation states

> size being the number of bytes you want to use

so if I want to use only 20 bytes from random address should I write `EEPROM.begin(20);`?

If it's not bug how to read from address 5000 if max number for begin method is 4096?